# Good Knowledgebase Script

Tags: php

I have been researching for a good clean knowledgebase script. Something as clean as http://expressionengine.com/knowledge_base/

But all the scripts which I have seen are either $200 plus or have a monthly charge etc. I am wondering if I have missed out on either an opensource or a cheaper script.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is a "knowledgebase script"?

Comment: Basically something that allows me to put questions and answers. A more advanced version of an FAQ. A script which helps me manage a knowledgebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will help future users or not. But I ended up purchasing WPWIKITHEME from the following URL: http://wpwikitheme.com/

I am not sure if it is really worth it or not. But I guess I like the Wordpress admin interface and am quite used to it.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found any good dedicated scripts, but could you use a wiki for this? [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) would be my recommendation if you decided to go this route.

Comment: I agree. Nowadays, you use Wikis for these sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

I've used 68KB http://68kb.com/ in the past and have been happy with it.  Best of all it's free.